# How to get the managed function name from the jitted output in SOS?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windbg, sos

I'm debugging the source code for [mscorlib](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/src/mscorlib)<sup>1</sup> with WinDbg/SOS. I'm curious, is it possible to get the managed function name if you see its address in assembly? For example, this is some of the code I'm seeing in the disassembly window:

```
00007ffd`7f035d7c 488d0d3d3af5ff  lea     rcx,[System_Private_CoreLib_ni+0x8797c0 (00007ffd`7ef897c0)]
00007ffd`7f035d83 e890728eff      call    System_Private_CoreLib_ni+0x20d018 (00007ffd`7e91d018)
00007ffd`7f035d88 488bf0          mov     rsi,rax
00007ffd`7f035d8b b9874a0000      mov     ecx,4A87h
00007ffd`7f035d90 e8834a91ff      call    System_Private_CoreLib_ni+0x23a818 (00007ffd`7e94a818)
00007ffd`7f035d95 488bc8          mov     rcx,rax
00007ffd`7f035d98 e87356b9ff      call    System_Private_CoreLib_ni+0x4bb410 (00007ffd`7ebcb410)
00007ffd`7f035d9d 488bd0          mov     rdx,rax
00007ffd`7f035da0 488bce          mov     rcx,rsi
00007ffd`7f035da3 e8e89fbdff      call    System_Private_CoreLib_ni+0x4ffd90 (00007ffd`7ec0fd90)
```

I want to find out what the names of some of these functions being `call`-ed are. I figure the command to use for this would be `!dumpmd`, but none of these commands seem to work:

```
!dumpmd 0x20d018
!dumpmd e890728eff
!dumpmd 00007ffd`7e91d018
```

All of them respond with "... is not a MethodDesc". How then can I get the managed function name from the assembly, or is it not possible?

<sup>1</sup> mscorlib was recently renamed `System.Private.CoreLib` for .NET Core, so that's why you see that instead of `mscorlib_ni`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
!dumpmd 0x20d018
```

can't work, because you only pass the offset relative to the module. Without specifying the module (System_Private_CoreLib_ni), `!dumpmd` cannot know what you're referring to.

```
!dumpmt e890728eff
```

can't work, because you pass machine code to `!dumpmt`. `e8` is the machine code for the assembly instruction `call` and the rest is a relative offset. To interpret that, `!dumpmt` would need to know the address of the instruction so that it can calculate the address of the method being called.

```
!dumpmt 00007ffd`7e91d018
```

could at least be plausible, because you pass an absolute address. That is a meaningful address. But it's not the address of a method table which `!dumpmt` expects.

With a given native address, you can use

> **!IP2MD <Code address>** Displays the MethodDesc structure at the specified address in code that has been JIT-compiled.

Actually the command will display much more, including the method name.

```
0:000> !ip2md 001fce80
MethodDesc:   00508ab4
Method Name:  ReporterCmd.Program+<>c..cctor()
Class:        0025e10c
MethodTable:  00508ad0
mdToken:      06000027
Module:       00193fbc
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     001fce48
Transparency: Critical
```

The [sosex](/questions/tagged/sosex) ([download](http://www.stevestechspot.com/SOSEXV40NowAvailable.aspx)) command `!mln` as implemented by @[Steve Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269097/steve-johnson) and mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38535419/480982) is really helpful, since it will auto detect the nearest useful thing, so you needn't know in detail what you have.

```
0:000> !mln 001fce80
Method instance: (BEGIN=001fce48)(MD=00508ab4 disassemble)[ReporterCmd.Program+<>c..cctor()]
```

If you're learning about .NET internals, I recommend using `!mln` and then finding out how to get the same results using other methods so that you know about the relationship of things.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the entire address to `!sosex.mln`